# Remove extra spacing in tables

Tags: tables, tabularx, booktabs

Hi guys I am new to LaTeX and I have a small issue with the spacings in a table that I made.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 10in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{.7\textwidth}{@{}ccccc@{}}

\toprule
& \cr{\bfseries Number of heaters}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Method 1}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Method 2} 
\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5} 
&Power/W
&Efficency/\%
&Power/W
&Efficency/\%
\\
\midrule
1 & 0.123 & 0.37 & 0.12 & 0.36 \\
2 & 0.250 & 0.39 & 0.21 & 0.36\\
3 & 0.345 & 0.36 & 0.35 & 0.34\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

The output of this looks like
[image]

As you can see there is some extra spacing on the right and some extra spacing on the top. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me remove this spacing.
Additionally another question ,does anyone know how I can align "Number of heaters" with the Power and Efficeny, insted of the Methods. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The extra horizontal space is due to the use of `tabularx` here. You could either use a regular `tabular` (as in `\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}`) if you're also fine with a narrower table or switch to `tabular*` (as in `\begin{tabular*}{.7\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc@{}}`)  if you want to evently distribute the white space among all columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 10in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Method 1}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Method 2} 
\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5} 
\bfseries Number of heaters 
& Power/W & Efficency/\%
& Power/W & Efficency/\%
\\
\midrule
1 & 0.123 & 0.37 & 0.12 & 0.36 \\
2 & 0.250 & 0.39 & 0.21 & 0.36\\
3 & 0.345 & 0.36 & 0.35 & 0.34\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{.7\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc@{}}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Method 1}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Method 2} 
\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5} 
\bfseries Number of heaters 
& Power/W & Efficency/\%
& Power/W & Efficency/\%
\\
\midrule
1 & 0.123 & 0.37 & 0.12 & 0.36 \\
2 & 0.250 & 0.39 & 0.21 & 0.36\\
3 & 0.345 & 0.36 & 0.35 & 0.34\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```